# Remove duplication with AbstractBehavior.createReceive

Tags: java, akka, akka-typed

when implementing an Akka Typed actor by extending createReceive, we will see something like this:

```
@Override
public Receive<Command> createReceive()
{
   return newReceiveBuilder()
           .onMessage(SomeCommand.class, s -> something())
           .build();
}
```

..with `something()` returning a `Behavior`, for example:

```
public Behavior<Command> something() 
{
     return Behaviors.receive(Command.class)
           .onMessage(SomeCommand.class, m -> something())
           .build();
}
```

But now we can see that `createReceive()` and `something()` being pretty much duplicates. In other words, whenever I return to the "initial" state, I will get this code duplication. So, the question is:

Can I somehow implement `createReceive()` by re-using the `something()` method? For example, is something like this possible...

```
@Override
public Receive<Command> createReceive()
{
   return Behaviors.behave( this::something);
}
```

(Of course, `Behaviors.behave` does not exist like this, the question is, does something like this exists, "converting" a Behavior to a receive?)

Comment: `Receive` is just a special `Behavior` (which brings up the question of what makes it special beyond that it was built using `ReceiveBuilder`), so you could turn it around and have your `something()` just be `return createReceive()`.

Comment: Since `Receive`/`Behavior` are really just functions in disguise, I also don't see why you couldn't save the built `Receive` in a field.

Comment: @LeviRamsey Thanks, that's a good suggestion, I only always tried it the other way without realizing that a `Receive` actually IS a `Behavior`. Still not sure why it is actually required, `createReceive` could easily be replaced by a `createBehavior()` and return a `Behavior`, removing the need for Receive at all.

Comment: It's interesting that the analogue in the scaladsl (I basically only use the functional style and the scaladsl) is `def onMessage(msg: T): Behavior[T]`.  The only plausible thing I can think of is that `Receive<T>` (to match the classic API) is the original typed OO API and it persists for backward compatibility and the functional API introduced the idea of `Behavior`.

Comment: See https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/31531

Answer (score 1):

Akka 2.7.0 will introduce an alternative API for defining a behavior which is basically a port of the Scala API.

```java
public class MyActor extends AbstractOnMessageBehavior<MyActor.Command>
    public static interface Command {}

    public static class SomeCommand extends Command {
        public static SomeCommand INSTANCE = new SomeCommand();
        private SomeCommand() {}
    }

    public MyActor(ActorContext<Command> context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Behavior<Command> onMessage(Command msg) {
      if (msg instanceof SomeCommand) { return something((SomeCommand)msg); }
      else return Behaviors.unhandled();
    }

    private Behavior<Command> something(SomeCommand sc) {
      // FIXME: actually do something useful
      return Behaviors.same()
    }
}
```

(Apologies if the Java is atrocious)

This API is likely slightly lower overhead than the current Java `AbstractBehavior` API: the `ReceiveBuilder` and `BehaviorBuilder` APIs are effectively compiling a domain-specific language like:

```java
newReceiveBuilder()
    .onMessage(SomeMessage.class, this::something)
    .build()
```

into

```java
if (msg instanceof SomeMessage) { return something((SomeMessage)msg); }
else return Behaviors.unhandled();
```

whenever an instance of this behavior handles its first message (i.e. when an actor handles its first message after transitioning to this behavior).  When staying in this behavior, there's also some overhead of checking if the `Receive` has been built already (though JIT may largely eliminate that).

The benefit of the `ReceiveBuilder`/`BehaviorBuilder` APIs is that the `instanceof` checks and casts are hidden: the developer ergonomic improvement is worth some small overhead.  The `AbstractOnMessageBehavior` lets you opt out of the builder APIs:

- You can, effectively, manually compile the builder into `instanceof` and cast like I did above (this will work on any Java version); if you're on Java 8/11 and want max performance, this might be worth trying (but always, always, benchmark!)
- You can use language features ("pattern matching") to have the Java compiler build the `instanceof`-and-cast logic... this should also make it easier to define a behavior in Kotlin or other JVM language which supports pattern matching.  This might even be more ergonomic than the builders.
- You can also use a different approach entirely (e.g. one leveraging virtual method dispatch)